# How can one extract number of trailing zeros from String

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to extract trailing zeros from a string for eg
//8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000
should yield
14
my approach was to first find the length of above string then subtract it by length of the 
stripped trailing zero string.
I tried to find the later using BigDecimal stripTrailingZeros() method but it is only removing zeros after decimal

for eg

1200.000 is converted to 1200 by stripTrailingZeros() method but i want 12 as output

any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is your question about Strings which are actually numbers or about BigDecimal?

Comment: Did you look at using some form of regex?

Comment: @vikingsteve Jon Skeet on his way :)

Comment: big decimal but if you know any solution using string methods then it will work too

Comment: What would be the correct (desired) answer for your 1200 example? Should it be 5 or 6?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest option would probably be to use `String.replaceAll`:

```
text = text.replaceAll("[0.]*$", "");
```

The `$` makes sure it's only trimming the end of the string.

Note that if you start with "0" you'll end up with an empty string - think about what you want the result to be in that situation.

Comment: But wouldn't this also include the '.' in the count? I thought the OP only wanted to count the trailing zeroes?

Comment: @DuncanKinnear: Well, I was going on the OP's requirement of "1200.00" being an input and "12" being an output. I'm assuming that they can add or subtract one at the appropriate point.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the length of trailing zeroes, you could do this regex :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("0+$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    m.find();
    String val = m.group();
    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println(val.length());

}
```

O/P :

```
00000000000000
14
```

Comment: @NitinJaiman  - **Beware** . You will get an error if you *don't* have trailing zeroes in the String. If you are *not-guaranteed* to have trailing zeroes, use *Jon Skeet*'s solution.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear - The OP hasn't mentioned that his String might contain decimal points. If there is a decimal point, then it will take the trailing zeroes after the point.

Comment: The OP's second example has '1200.000' as the input. He says he wants to strip all but the '12'. He states he tried to use `BigDecimal` `stripTrailingZeroes()` but he said that "it is only removing zeros after decimal", which is exactly what your example is also doing.

Answer (score 0):

well - this is simple but a compute-intesiv solution...

```
String str = "8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000";
System.out.println(str);
int count = 0;
char c = '0';
do {
    c = str.charAt(str.length()-1);
    if (c == '0' ){
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        count ++;
    }
}while(c == '0' );
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println("amount:"+amount);
```

but it's a very obvious solution...  (just remove last zero...until there is no more...)

Comment: where is the *loop counter* ?. Your loop is *infinite*.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer fulfills your requirement?

```
String str = "8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000";
    String withoutTrailingZeroes = "";
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String charFromString = Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
        if (charFromString.equals("0")) {
            withoutTrailingZeroes += str.charAt(i);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(str.replace(withoutTrailingZeroes, "")); // string without trailing zeros
    System.out.println(withoutTrailingZeroes); // trailing zeroes
    System.out.println(withoutTrailingZeroes.length()); // trailing zeroes length
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, expanding on Jon's answer, and assuming that you don't want to count the decimal point, then the following code should cope with both integers and decimal numbers in your string:

```
// Start by taking note of the original string length
int startLength = text.length();
// Remove any trailing zeroes
text = text.replaceAll("0*$", "");
// Remove any zeroes immediately to the left of any trailing decimal point
text = text.replaceAll("0*.$", ".");
// Find the number of zeroes by subtracting the lengths
int numZeroes = startLength - text.length();
```

or if you want it in a single statement:

```
int numZeroes = text.length() - text.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("0*.$", ".").length();
```

Which looks horrible, but has the advantage of not altering the original string.